# FormRequest for the second job scrapy

Tags: scrapy

The navigation is doing by POST filled form
First scraped result is ok.

```
{
        def start_requests(self):
            for search in self.searchs:
                for u in self.start_urls:
                    self.cursor.execute("UPDATE motcleazloop SET nb=nb+1")
                    self.conn.commit()
                    frmdata = {"q": search}
                    return [FormRequest  (url=u, method="POST", formdata=frmdata, callback=self.parse_o)]

    def parse_o(self,response):
        #count the number of forms in the response
        print 'number of forms:'
        print len(response.css('form'))
        sel = Selector(response)

        #Call item function
        item = SniffyduckItem()

        #Extract items to a array
        item['urls'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id=\'links\']/*/*/*/*/@href').extract()

        # Process item
        yield item

        # Call next job of the robot
        yield self.loop_a(response)

    def loop_a(self,response):
#        print response.body
        nbforms = len(response.css('form'))
        if nbforms == 3:
            print "4"
            yield FormRequest.from_response (response, formnumber=2, callback=self.parse_o)
        elif nbforms == 4:
            print "3"
            yield FormRequest.from_response (response, formnumber=3, callback=self.parse_o)
        else:
            # if only 2 forms
            exit(0)
}
```

Error:

> 2018-02-24 10:50:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return
>   Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'list' in

Answer (score 0):

return FormRequest instead of [FormRequest], you should delete []